# ARM scatter file - How to preserve Flash Data inside Execution Region

Tags: linker, arm, scatter

I'm using ARM Compiler+Linker for STM32 MCU.

When HEX is generated I use tool srec_cat to calculate and write CRC into specific address inside HEX. When this happen I can see in my HEX this CRC correctly.

The problem is in Execution time, this value disappears and is rewritten by value 0.

Here is my scatter file:

```
LR_IROM1 0x08000000 0x000FE00  {    ; load region size_region
ER_IROM1 0x08000000 0x00FE00  {  ; load address = execution address    ; 64kB - 12kB = 53248 B  (ILR Output -O0 = 52496 B) ; For PTB MUST use optimization -O1 or stronger!  
startup_stm32l100xba.o (RESET, +First)
vectortable.o (VECTORS)
* (+RO)
}  
RW_IRAM1 0x20000000 0x00002000  {  ; RW data
.ANY (+RW +ZI)
}
}

LR_IROM3 0x0800FE00 0x0000200 { ; // 512B for Production Constants
ER_CONST_ROM3 0x0800FE00 FIXED 0x0000200 { ; // 512B for Production Constants
    ;params.o (PARAM, +First)
}
}
```

What I do in post process by srec_cat tool is that I write CRC at address 0x0800FE08.
When I read HEX file by STM32 Link utility I can see this value correctly.
But when I debug the code at the address 0x0800FE08 is value 0.
I have tried UNINIT parameter but it doesn't work.

What work for me is that i specify in assembly file special AREA where I put some dummy DWORDs which are rewritten by srec_cat tool and then I can read in execution time the CRC value correctly.
Here is the code:

```
       AREA    PARAM, DATA, READWRITE
            EXPORT  APP_CRC
            EXPORT  WEL_CRC 

__PARAM
APP_CRC         DCD     0xAAAABBBB                     
WEL_CRC         DCD     0xCCCCDDDD                

            ALIGN

            AREA    |.text|, CODE, READONLY
END
```

But there must be another way how to preserve the data from HEX file and use in same time at_address directive within same Execution Region.
I want to put fixed value into address 0x0800FE00 by:

const u32 U32_Product_SN  **attribute**((at(0x0800FE00))) = 1;

and I want to keep what is already at HEX file added by post process operation at address 0x0800FE08. And I don't want to use the trick with assembly file and AREA directive.

Do you know what to do to preserve CRC value generated by srec_cat tool even at runtime, execution time?

Answer (score 1):

OK I have found the problem.

It's simple, when I explore HEX file everything with CRCs was OK, but in debug mode it is used AXF(ELF file) instead of HEX which only belongs to my post process modifications.

So to see CRC correctly in debug mode I have to modify also AXF.

Comment: For hints on how to inject CRC into AXF/ELF see https://stackoverflow.com/a/24166197/2380383