# objcopy is removing a section unless I declare a static volatile variable in that section (using attribute)

Tags: gcc, linker, arm, binaryfiles, objcopy

I have a linker script in which I have defined a section for containing the checksum of a software image. Something like:

```
...
.my_checksum :
  {
    __checksum_is_here = .;
    KEEP (*(.my_checksum))
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _sw_image_code_end = .;  
  } > IMAGE
...
```

The checksum is placed into that section by using `objcopy --update-section`.

I build an `elf` file by using the `arm gcc` compiler, and I can see this section and its value within it:

```
> arm-none-eabu-objdumph -h my_elf_file.elf
...
0 .text         0001496c  08010000  08010000  00010000  2**4
...
7 .my_checksum     00000004  080250c0  080250c0  000350c0  2**2
...

// Notice that 000350c0 is the file offset and 080250c0 is the LMA.
// The starting LMA is 08010000
```

And I can retrieve its value:

```
> xxd -s 0x000350c0 -l 4 my_elf_file.elf
000350c0: 015e 028e // I have checked this value and it is correct.
```

Now I generate a `bin` file by executing

```
> arm-none-eabi-objcopy -O binary --gap-fill 0xFF -S my_elf_file.elf my_elf_file.bin
```

Now, if I try to read the checksum value again, using the difference between the checksum LMA and the first section LMA (see above):

```
> xxd -s 0x150c0 -l 4 my_elf_file.bin
```

The result I obtain here is different from the one obtained in the elf file, that is, the checksum section has been removed by objcopy. (That's what I think at least).

Nevertheless, If I define this in my `main.c` file:

```
static volatile unsigned int __aux_checksum __attribute__((section(".my_checksum")));
...
int main() {
  ...
  ((void)__aux_checksum); // Avoid compiler/linker optimizations.
  ...
}
```

Now, if I replicate the same steps as above with the `elf` and `bin` files (using the proper offsets), I can retrieve the checksum from the `bin` file (`elf` and `bin` give the same result).

### Questions

**My first question is:** I know that you can define a section using `__attribute__((section))`, but if you use a section already defined within the linker script, does this command changes its behaviour for placing the variable within the section, instead of creating a new one?

**My second question is:** Is this the only way for preventing `objcopy` of removing this particular section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets answer your 2nd question first,

> Is this the only way for preventing objcopy of removing this particular section?

You need a concept as documented in the [gnu LD manual](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/4/html/Using_ld_the_GNU_Linker/sections.html) under **SECTIONS**.

---

> 4.6.8.1. Output Section Type
>
> Each output section may have a type. The type is a keyword in parentheses. The following types are defined:

```
NOLOAD
```

> The section should be marked as not loadable, so that it will not be loaded into memory when the program is run.

```
DSECT, COPY, INFO, OVERLAY
```

> These type names are supported for backward compatibility, and are rarely used. They all have the same effect: the section should be marked as not allocatable, so that no memory is allocated for the section when the program is run.
>
> The linker normally sets the attributes of an output section based on the input sections which map into it. You can override this by using the section type. For example, in the script sample below, the ROM section is addressed at memory location 0 and does not need to be loaded when the program is run. The contents of the ROM section will appear in the linker output file as usual.

```
SECTIONS {
  ROM 0 (NOLOAD) : { … }
  …
}
```

---

So what does that mean?  Say you have debugging info in your objects.  If you are burning a ROM image you probably don't want to place the debugging info in the object.  As well, the BSS segment is all zero and there is no need to store it to ROM, but you need to clear our RAM (at the load address) to make way for it.  The 'init value' for the `.data` section is initialized from ROM but resides in RAM.  The concepts are 'loadable' and 'allocatable' and they have flags for them in an ELF file.  By default your `.my_checksum` gets no flags.  Ie, not allocated and not loadable like debug info.

> I know that you can define a section using **attribute**((section)), but if you use a section already defined within the linker script, does this command changes its behaviour for placing the variable within the section, instead of creating a new one?

From the above,

> The linker normally sets the attributes of an output section based on the input sections which map into it.

Your input sections flags get inherited by your output section.  So you have put in at least allocatable as a flag.

I would suggest that you just put your checksum at the end of either `.text` or `.data`.  For instance, input secttions `.rodata` (constant values) usually get put with the output `.text`.  There is usually no need to invent another output sections unless you want some book keeping that wont get to the final image.  Your `__checksum_is_here` label is sufficient to find it and you can look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24150030/storing-crc-into-an-axf-elf-file) on CRCs.

Comment: There are also concepts like a vector table that are hardware intrinsic that you need software addresses for but you don't really load them; but you might still call them allocated.  Allocated affects how LD will assign addresses.  You can be crude and use constants cast to pointers, but a linker file is a good place to centrally contain all this system address information.

Comment: Another point is that `objcopy` is only going to copy 'loadable' sections unless you specifically specify them.  So it won't copy `.bss` by default for instance.